# How to remove unwanted spaces between input fields in form

Tags: html, forms, input

I have this code below which I have built in order for it to be ALL on the same line. Problem is, for some reason the form input field is several spaces away from the label. Thus something like this happens:

https://jsfiddle.net/pswLLhru/

Any help so as to remove the extra spacing between the two input fields? 
Thank you

```
label {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 130px;
}


<div class="block">
    <label>Currently I am </label>
    <input type="text" id="labelinput" style="width:60px;"/>
    <label> in </label>
    <input type="text" id="labelinput" style="width:60px"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Remove the `width: 130px` property?

Comment: you don't need to explicitly add a width to elements. They will take all the space they need. so like @Boaz said, remove the width property. and since labels/inputs are 'inline' elements, they will, by default, go on the same line. (unless if you have a label with a lot of text that takes up an entire line) https://jsfiddle.net/gom7sLxt/1/

Comment: Hi @boaz that brought the fields a little more to the left, still at least 3 space keys away from the labels!

Comment: @Snowmate Try removing the redundant spaces included in your markup as well. For example note the redundant space in `<label>Currently I am*</label>` (marked with a star). Also, newline characters are probably interpreted as spaces as well, remove them too.

Comment: I don't see the issue after removing the `width`: https://jsfiddle.net/04b6axtv/

Answer (score 1):

Just deleting your CSS:

```
label {
display:inline-block;
width: 130px;
}
```

will remove the white space from your inputs and show your div with the 2 inputs on the same line.

Also I would recommend indenting your code to make it easier to read in larger/future projects.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the `width` in your css and use comments in your markup

```
<div class="block">
    <label>Currently I am </label><!--
    --><input type="text" id="labelinput" style="width:60px;"/><!--
    --><label> in </label><!--
    --><input type="text" id="labelinput" style="width:60px"/>
</div>
```